# Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in Laravel Illuminate Container.php

Tags: laravel, illuminate-container

I recently tried creating a new Laravel project using the `laravel new` command and going to the {projectname}.test domain returns the error Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /Users/.../blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
I have my computer's version of php 7.4 required in my composer.json file and I am using Laravel Installer 4.2.4. My projects created in a CMS built with Laravel all show up fine when typing their .test domains so I'm not sure what is wrong with this installation/the Illuminate container. Any advice greatly appreciated, thanks!